# Удаление объектов в динамическом массиве

Tags: c++

У меня есть динамических массив из тяжёлых объектов (к примеру, из пять объектов класса std::string). Как мне удалить этот массив так, чтобы все ресурсы, занятые строками, были освобождены? Как известно, вручную использовать деструктор нельзя, т.к. это UB.

Comment: "У меня есть динамических массив, но это секретная информация _ не покажу..."

Comment: С чего вы решили, что вызов деструктора вручную это UB?

Answer (score 3):

Если для создания элементов Вы вызывали `new`, вызывайте парный `delete`, для `new[]` - `delete[]`. И все деструкторы будут вызваны. Но так как у Вас с++, используйте `std::vector<std::string>` и проблем с "неосвобождённой памятью" будет на порядок меньше.